# Getting an unexpected results while updating the value in chrome local storage using chrome.storage.local.set() while creating an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

> Initially the data stored in chrome browser local storage is

```
 `{
    storedGroupsData: {
        grp1: [
            {},{}
        ]
    }
}`
```

> when I try add another group say 'grp2' i want this

```
{
storedGroupsData: {
    grp1: [
        {},{}
    ],
    grp2:[
        {},{}
    ]
}
```

}

> but i am getting this

```
{
storedGroupsData: {
    grp2: [
        {},{}
    ],
    storedGroupsData:{
       grp2: [
        {},{}
       ]
    }

}
```

}

> The code is

```
import getTabData from "./getTabData.js";

 const createGroup = async (selectedTabs, groupName) => {
const groupData = [];
let storedGroupsData;

try {
```

retrieving the data stored in the local storage

```
  storedGroupsData = await chrome.storage.local.get('storedGroupsData');
    storedGroupsData = storedGroupsData || { }
    console.log(storedGroupsData);

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

*pushing the tabInfo in the groupData array*

```
for (const tabId of selectedTabs) {
    const tabInfo = await getTabData(tabId, groupName);
    groupData.push(tabInfo);
}
```

*creating a new group*

```
const newGroup = {
    [groupName]: groupData
};
```

*updating the storedGroupsData and saving it in local storage using chrome.storage.local.se() function provided by the chrome extension api*

```
try {
         const modifiedStoredGroupsData = { ...storedGroupsData, ...newGroup };
         console.log(modifiedStoredGroupsData);
         await chrome.storage.local.set({'storedGroupsData' : modifiedStoredGroupsData});
         storedGroupsData[groupName] = groupData;
         await chrome.storage.local.set({storedGroupsData})
    } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
  };

 
 export default createGroup;
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of `get` is not the value of the key, but an object `{[key]: value}` so to obtain the value you need to read `[key]` of the result:

```js
let data = (await chrome.storage.local.get('storedGroupsData')).storedGroupsData || {};
```

Also remove the second `set` call as it's an unnecessary duplicate.